# Detect if tap is inside or outside custom calloutView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a map with some pins. When I click on a Pin, a custom callout appears as a UIView. When i tap inside the calloutView, nothing should happen.. If I tap outside the view, the custom calloutView should dissappear. But I dont know how to implement that, either it disappears at taps inside and outside the view or it doesnt disappear at all.

my func to handle taps:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view == customCallout {
        return
    } else {
        customCallout?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

In this case, it deletes on both taps the custom callout.. Here I create the callout:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return
    }
    //this creates the callout
    let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: nil, options: nil)
    let calloutView =  views?[0] as! CustomCalloutView
    calloutView.delegate = self
    customCallout = calloutView
}
```

how can I implement that if i tap inside the custom callout view, it doesnt disappear but in the case that i tap outside, it does disappear?

Answer (score 0):

The old [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW28) outlines the process. The technique involves implementing a `hitTest` method for your annotation view that includes hits within your custom callout. Otherwise the touches are not recognized as being part of the annotation view and/or callout, but rather on the map.

As the [Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW28) says:

> When you use a custom view instead of a standard callout, you need to do extra work to make sure your callout shows and hides appropriately when users interact with it. The steps below outline the process for creating a custom callout that contains a button:
>
> 1. Design an NSView or UIView subclass that represents the custom callout. It’s likely that the subclass needs to implement the drawRect: method to draw your custom content.
> 2. Create a view controller that initializes the callout view and performs the action related to the button.
> 3. In the annotation view, implement hitTest: to respond to hits that are outside the annotation view’s bounds but inside the callout view’s bounds, as shown in Listing 6-7.
> 4. In the annotation view, implement setSelected:animated: to add your callout view as a subview of the annotation view when the user clicks or taps it. If the callout view is already visible when the user selects it, the setSelected: method should remove the callout subview from the annotation view (see Listing 6-8).
> 5. In the annotation view’s initWithAnnotation: method, set the canShowCallout property to NO to prevent the map from displaying the standard callout when the user selects the annotation.
> 6. Listing 6-7 shows an example of implementing hitTest: to handle hits in the callout view that might be outside the bounds of the annotation view.
>
> Listing 6-7  Responding to hits within a custom callout
>
> ```
> - (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)point
> {
>     NSView *hitView = [super hitTest:point];
>     if (hitView == nil && self.selected) {
>         NSView *calloutView = self.calloutViewController.view;
>         NSPoint pointInCalloutView = [self convertPoint:point toView:calloutView];
>         hitView = [calloutView hitTest:pointInCalloutView];
>     }
>     return hitView;
> }
> ```
>
> Listing 6-8 shows an example of implementing setSelected:animated: to animate the arrival and dismissal of a custom callout view when the user selects the annotation view.
>
> Listing 6-8  Adding and removing a custom callout view
>
> ```
> - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
> {
>     [super setSelected:selected];
>
>     // Get the custom callout view.
>     NSView *calloutView = self.calloutViewController.view;
>     if (selected) {
>         NSRect annotationViewBounds = self.bounds;
>         NSRect calloutViewFrame = calloutView.frame;
>       // Center the callout view above and to the right of the annotation view.
>         calloutViewFrame.origin.x = -(NSWidth(calloutViewFrame) - NSWidth(annotationViewBounds)) * 0.5;
>         calloutViewFrame.origin.y = -NSHeight(calloutViewFrame) + 15.0;
>         calloutView.frame = calloutViewFrame;
>
>         [self addSubview:calloutView];
>     } else {
>         [calloutView.animator removeFromSuperview];
>     }
> }
> ```

Now, the above is obviously Objective-C (and your implementation of listing 6-8 is likely to be be different than theirs), but the basic pattern is the same in Swift. See this [CustomMapViewAnnotationCalloutSwift](https://github.com/robertmryan/CustomMapViewAnnotationCalloutSwift) Github repo that illustrates how to implement custom annotation views (including this desired `hitTest` behavior) in Swift. So, it’s a combination of implementing `hitTest` in the annotation view, as well as obviously having the callout consume those touches, as well.